# How to connect a bash or shell to a lxd container

Tags: lxd

I have many lxd containers on my system. I cannot access them from network i do not have passwords

Is there a way to attach a bash like we can do on docker for example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable networking on the remote LXD:

```
lxc config set core.https_address [::]:8443
lxc config set core.trust_password PASSWORD
```

Add the target host as a remote (it will ask for `PASSWORD`):

```
lxc remote add REMOTE_NAME IP_ADDRESS
```

Run commands on the remote system:

```
lxc exec REMOTE_NAME:CONTAINER COMMAND
```

To get a shell you can pass `bash` or `sh` as command in most cases.

More here:
https://web.archive.org/web/20160818010904/https://www.stgraber.org/2016/04/12/lxd-2-0-remote-hosts-and-container-migration-612/